# How to perform firebase robo test recording (espresso) with standalone android app (.apk file) on android studio?

Tags: firebase, firebase-test-lab

I have app (.apk file) and I need to do testing using firebase robo test (espresso recorder) on android studio.
We don't have access to source code except the .apk file.

Is it possible? And how to do it, launch app in android studio emulator and perform robo test recording?

Comment: Also posted on: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/uxqnp2TbRuM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, both Espresso Test Recorder and Robo Script Recorder are fully integrated into Android Studio workflows that require access to the source code of the app-under-test. So, no, it is not possible to record a Robo test having just an .apk file. But feel free to file a corresponding feature request. Thanks!

Comment: where i can submit a feature request?

Comment: You can submit a feature request here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192775 Thank you!